# Replace Alphabet with another Alphabet in List

Tags: c#

I have a list

```
List<string> myList = new List<string>();
myList.Add("A");
myList.Add("B");
myList.Add("C");
...
...
...
myList.Add("Z");
```

Now I want to replace `A with N`, `B with X` and `so on..........`

I know there is `Replace(string, string)`.

But is there any easy way to do that?

Comment: easier than just a method call?

Comment: @Hassan I have to check every time that if character in List is A, then replace it with N,...... So I am asking the above question.

Comment: you want to replace all "A" with one method call?

Comment: @Hassan Yes that is exactly what I want.

Comment: Is there a pattern to this replacement. A to N and B to X seems arbitrary, and if it is you need to use 'if' or 'switch'. If there is a rule, such as replace each letter a letter behind it in alphabet then you could write some smarter code (I will edit my answer if it is so).

Comment: Did you know that in C# 3 and above you can say `new List<string>() { "A", "B", "C", "D" };` ?  It's a lot shorter.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

mrzli's answer is not bad but I would suggest an enhancement to it. Rather than writing a whole pile of code, I would write a map:

```
var map = new Dictionary<string, string>() {
  {"A", "N"},
  {"B", "Z"},  // ... etc
};
var newList = originalList.Select(x=>map[x]).ToList();
```

Comment: I like the dictionary approach, but creating a new list would cause anything referencing the original list to not benefit from the new values.  I think the question is asking how to modify the individual values of the original list.

Answer (score 3):

I feel like a dictionary here would be useful and reusable.  For instance if you wanted to create an extension method like .MaskValue() or something.  In any case, if you really want to replace the values in the list:

```
var listOfLetters = new List<string> { "A", "B" };

var dictionarySwap = new Dictionary<string,string>{{"A","N"},{"B","X"}};

for (int i = 0; i < listOfLetters.Count; i++)
{
    listOfLetters[i] = dictionarySwap[listOfLetters[i]];
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You could try something like this (requires .NET 3.5):

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    List<string> myList = new List<string>();
    myList.Add("A");
    myList.Add("B");
    myList.Add("C");

    myList = myList.Select(x => Modify(x)).ToList();
}

private static string Modify(string input)
{
    if (input == "A")
    {
        return "N";
    }
    else if (input == "B")
    {
        return "X";
    }
    else
    {
        return input;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`IndexOf`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e4w08k17%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), which will give you the index of the element you are trying to look up.

```
List<string> myList = new List<string>();
myList.Add("A");
myList.Add("B");
myList.Add("C");

// find "A", then replace its contents with "N"
myList[myList.IndexOf("A")] = "N";
```

This will only replace the first found element, so you will have to run this line multiple times if you expect many `"A"`s in your list.

Answer (score 0):

if you have just a string variable you i think the easiest way is Replace Function. 
however i have a simple extension method witch is very handy on enumerables so let me show you what i do in such cases, this is my function:

```
    public static class Extensions
    {
        public static void ForeEach<T>(this IEnumerable<T> instance, Action<T> action)
        {
            foreach (T item in instance)
            {
               action(item);
            }
       }
    }
```

in your case:

```
List<string> values = new List<string>();
        values.Add("A");
        values.Add("C");
        values.Add("D");
        values.Add("E");
        values.Add("F");
        values.Add("G");
        values.Add("A");

        values.ForEach(a => { if (a == "A") { a = "new value"; } });
```

i hope i understood you mean :D